# Finding number of elements within a given range in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, range

For example, lets say I have an array with the integers:

> 1 3 4 9 10

I want to find the number of elements between 1 and 9 (inclusive), so it should return 4 (as there are 4 integers [1,3,4,9] that are between one and nine inclusive).

One way I thought about doing this was to first place each integer *J* in the *Jth* position of the array so queries of whether the integer exists can be done in constant time. Then you can simply go through the range and check whether each number exists, but this takes too long for large numbers.

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: run through the array with an if and a counter

Comment: if (num <= high && num >= low) ++counter;

Comment: That runs in linear O(N) time. Amit's answer gives O(2lg(N)) which is even better! [lg(N) is log base 2]

Comment: it is! I was impressed with it and upvoted it too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just place the elements in a sorted array, then on query use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (twice) to find the lower and upper number, you get two indices `l (lower),u (upper)`. The answer is then `u-l + 1`

**Complexity** is `O(logN)` - where `N` is number of elements in your array.

Indexing complexity (initializing the array, done only once) is `O(nlogn)` for sotring.

in your example:

- binary search for 1 yields l=0
- binary search for 9 yield u=3
- answer = u-l+1 = 3-0+1 = 4

Note: If the array contains dupes or the numbers might not exist - some extra work is needed - but the idea how to do it remains the same.

Comment: This seems to be the best. Faster than going through the array every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Amit answer is good if left and right interval are part of the array, what if array is

```
1 2 3 5 7 9 10
```

and interval is [2 8]
In this case you cant search for 8 using binary search and wont get the count

The only solution i can think of is

```
for(int i=0;i<size_array;i++){
if(arr[i] >=left || arr[i] <= right)
count++;
}
```

can anyone come with a better solution ?